# How to show the name of the month in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this code but I need to show the name of the month instead of the number (e.g., 11 = November, 12 = December, and so on).

```sql
SELECT extract(month FROM date_ordered) Month,
(date_ordered) AS "DATE ORDERED", SUM (quantity * unit_price) AS "TOTAL AMOUNT"
FROM ingredient_purchase_list
GROUP BY (date_ordered) HAVING SUM(quantity * unit_price) > 20;
```

How I can display month names instead of numbers?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `to_char` function.

```
SELECT to_char(date_ordered, 'Month') Month, (date_ordered) AS "DATE ORDERED"
    , SUM (quantity * unit_price) AS "TOTAL AMOUNT" 
FROM ingredient_purchase_list GROUP BY (date_ordered) HAVING SUM(quantity * unit_price) > 20;
```